# How to correctly define Accept-Encoding: gzip header in RAML?

Tags: mule, raml

I need to describe a REST API  that always returns gzipped response in terms of [RAML 1.0 specification](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-10).

The API RAML specification must indicate that the API requires the header [Accept-Encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.3) be always sent in the request.
Furthermore, the Accept-Encoding value must be either '*' or 'gzip' or have 'gzip' among other acceptable encodings specified e.g. 'compress, gzip' or 'compress;q=0.5, gzip;q=1.0'.

As a first iteration, I've defined the mandatory header like this:

```
headers:    
  Accept-Encoding:
    type: string
    required: true
    example: 'gzip'
```

But this, of course, does not indicate that only 'gzip' encoding is supported by the API.
Pls help with defining more detail RAML specification for the 'Accept-Encoding' header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RAML doesn't has the expressiveness to validate the values with specific rules. You can set a [pattern](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-10/raml-10.md/#scalar-types) with a regular expression to restrict the value:

```yaml
headers:    
  Accept-Encoding:
    type: string
    required: true
    example: 'gzip'
    pattern: ^(\*|((.+,)?\s*gzip\s*((,|;).+)?))$
```

This pattern doesn't guarantee the value will be a valid list but it verifies that it is either only `*` or `gzip` standalone or surrounded in either side by commas. You could improve the regular expression to ensure that both sides are comma separated lists, however that kind of validation is outside of what is expected of RAML and belongs in the application code.

Comment: Thanks, this is a best idea so far. I just was hoping that there is more correct way of defining the header parameter as an array with elements separated by comma or semicolon with one mandatory element equal to '*' or 'gzip'

Comment: Why would that be more or less correct as long it is valid by the RAML spec? You probably mean something more specific to this use case. Pattern seems to fit.

Comment: The pattern in the example you provided allows only one value - 'gzip'. While as per the RFC, Accept-Encoding  can be a set of values separated by comma or semicolon. Furthermore, there is a special value '*'  which allows all encodings including gzip so it is valid as well. I've provided some of the examples in the original question. While you can read the RFC (the link in the original question as well) to get more examples.

Comment: I misunderstood that you were asking to restrict to gzip only. The link is good for reference but questions should be self contained. Do you have an actual list of values plus * to accept?

Comment: The standard itself does not restrict the list of the values. But in my case the API needs ONE OF the values in the attribute provided be equal to 'gzip' or '*'.

Comment: Actually, the original question describes the requirement pretty clear imho: "the Accept-Encoding value must be either '*' or 'gzip' or have 'gzip' among other acceptable encodings specified e.g. 'compress, gzip'.

Comment: I updated my answer with a better regular expression and an explanation.

Comment: It could be semicolon as well,, e.g. 'compress;q=0.5, gzip;q=1.0'

Comment: I update the regular expression so that after gzip it could be either a comma or a semicolon